# how to restore postgres database in docker when docker container not start?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I want to create a database in PostgreSQL and restore a backup in a docker container. I am able to create the database and run the docker container, and then run the `pg_restore` to restore the backup.
My Dockerfile is :

```
FROM postgres:latest

ENV POSTGRES_USER postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD 123qwe 
ENV POSTGRES_DB docker_pg 

COPY createTable.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Then I run the command for restore the backup :

```
docker exec -i 0d96d6b59d74 pg_restore -U postgres -d docker_pg< backup_latest.sql
```

It is working fine.

But my requirement is when I run the command for create the docker container database creation and restore the backup both work done in same time, mean at the time of container creation.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But my requirement is when I run the command for create the docker
> container **database creation and restore the backup both work done in
> same time, mean at the time of container creation.**

Both tasks can be performed by the Docker container all you need to place the restore script in the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder.

```
COPY createTable.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/a_createTable.sql
COPY backup_latest.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

As I changed `createTable.sql` to `a_createTable.sql`, so it will first create Table and then it will restore the backup.

> These initialization files will be executed in sorted name order as
> defined by the current locale

[Initialization scripts](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)

Or the other option is to create single SQL file and the order will be

```
ALL DDL 
# then 
ALL DML
```

so something like

```
COPY db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Comment: It is not working . Backup file is not restored . @Adiii

Comment: did you `use database` in the start of backup file? or if create table work it should also. can post `docker logs -f container_id` there might indication

Comment: I have a backup file where the create table and backup is together. When I copy createTable.sql its' working fine. Problem with the backup file. If I run the backup file after create the container with `docker exec -i 0d96d6b59d74 pg_restore -U postgres -d docker_pg< backup_latest.sql` this command. it is working fine.

Comment: the reason is the db container will first bkup script, because order, change creat_Table.sql to `a.sql` so it will be run before backup and your backup should work fine, did you tried with suggested changes?